# AIX apache rpm dependencies

Tags: apache, unix, rpm, dependency-management, aix

I am evaluating the [Crowd SSO](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) by Atlassian. Now to get apache to use Crowd for authentication, there is a [connector](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Integrating+Crowd+with+Apache#IntegratingCrowdwithApache-Step3.ChoosingtheCorrectApacheConnectorforyourOperatingSystem) available by the vendor.

### Problem

Unfortunately they do not provide anything for my OS (AIX). Instead they provide [source code with instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Installing+the+Crowd+Apache+Connector+on+Other+UNIX-Like+Systems). Now the example here uses `yum -y install autoconf automake gcc httpd-devel libcurl-devel libtool libxml2-devel mod_dav_svn subversion-devel` to download the required packages for which there is no alternate in AIX (AFAIK).

So I went to the [AIX toolbox](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html) and got some packages. For the rest, I took [Mr Perzl's](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php) help. And while installing the `rpms` ended up getting dependency errors.

### Question

Do I go with

1. The solution given here [dependency hell](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=FAQs.FAQs#rpm-dependency-hell).
2. [IBM way](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.install/doc/insgdrf/HT_insgdrf_install_opensrc.htm)
3. Something else which Google and my limited exposure to AIX are not telling me.

I am not `*nix` expert, rather at basic user level. And any installations are actually done by the admins. I need expert advice so as to get it right and efficiently if possible.

---

Appreciate if someone would like to retag this question for getting attention from the right people.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I struggled with AIX and Linux, and have success with the Crowd Connector on Linux.  So, having taken a look at both links, I would say:

The IBM documentation is only for the packages supplied with their Toolbox and there is a risk  that if you use it for other things, you may end up with a dead-end as the utilities may refuse to play ball.

With Mr. Perzl's way, you are building it brick by brick, with known certainty.  The main risk is that the right versions may not be available and/or one of the build tools may not work.  In that case, you may still have to tweak the source and/or the build/make files to compile properly, but it will eventually work.

Once you have a compiled plugin and it works with a certain version of Apache, you will not need many of the dependencies, so the instructions you give to the admins to deploy will be minimal.  Most likely, the runtime dependencies will be `mod_dav_svn, curl and libxml`

Please post an update when you get it working.